# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet after adding a crudrepositority

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa

My Spring server is working right (simple site showing a googlemap). But when I want to add a crudrepository (and of course a @Entity) the application doesn't find the same URI that before was working. How can I fix this?

**A piece of the system output:**

> 16:32:29.737 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager'
>   16:32:29.737 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@186fc102]
>   16:32:29.738 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'serverProperties'
>   16:32:29.739 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'managementServerProperties'
>   16:32:29.739 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletConfigInitParams]
>   16:32:29.739 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletContextInitParams]
>   16:32:29.739 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletContextInitParams] with type [String] and value 'dev'
>   16:32:29.751 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'sample' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.sample]
>   16:32:29.751 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'sample': initialization completed in 7745 ms
>   16:32:29.751 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Servlet 'sample' configured successfully
>   16:32:29.757 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'sample' processing GET request for [/mapa/hello]
>   16:32:29.759 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /hello
>   16:32:29.761 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/hello]
>   16:32:29.761 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /hello
>   16:32:29.762 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/hello]
>   16:32:29.762 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mapa/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'sample'
>   16:32:29.772 [690530332@qtp-1564826387-0] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request

**Application.java**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=palmaslab.mapas.repository.PostoSaude.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses       =palmaslab.mapas.repository.PostoSaudeRepository.class/*.PostoSaudeRepository.class*/)
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="palmaslab.mapas.controller")
public class Application {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultiPartConfigFactory factory = new MultiPartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize("256KB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("256KB");
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

**MyController**

```
@Controller
    public class myController {
    @Autowired
private PostoSaudeRepository PostosSaude;

//get postos!!
@RequestMapping("hello")
public ModelAndView showMessage(
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("mapa");
//  mv.addObject("postossaude", PostosSaude.findAll());
    return mv;
}}
```

**PostoSaudeRepository**

```
public interface PostoSaudeRepository extends CrudRepository<PostoSaude,Long> {
    public PostoSaude findById(long id);
}
```

**PostoSaude (Entity)**

```
@Entity
public class PostoSaude {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String nome_posto_saude;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private String endereco;
private String barrio_ou_nome_municipio; //aqui se coloca o nome do municipio, por exemplo Caucaia, o String cidade nesse caso ficará vazio ""
private String cidade;
private String estado;
private String pais;

public PostoSaude()
{}

public PostoSaude(String nome_posto_saude, String endereco,String barrio_ou_nome_municipio,String cidade, String estado, String pais)
{
    this.nome_posto_saude = nome_posto_saude;
    this.endereco = endereco;
    this.barrio_ou_nome_municipio = barrio_ou_nome_municipio;
    this.cidade = cidade;
    this.estado = estado;
    this.pais = pais;

}

public String getBarrio_ou_nome_municipio() {
    return barrio_ou_nome_municipio;
}

public void setBarrio_ou_nome_municipio(String barrio_ou_nome_municipio) {
    this.barrio_ou_nome_municipio = barrio_ou_nome_municipio;
}

public String getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(String cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public String getPais() {
    return pais;
}

public void setPais(String pais) {
    this.pais = pais;
}

public String getNome_posto_saude() {
    return nome_posto_saude;
}

public void setNome_posto_saude(String nome_posto_saude) {
    this.nome_posto_saude = nome_posto_saude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double d) {
    this.latitude = d;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double d) {
    this.longitude = d;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // Google Guava provides great utilities for hashing
    return Objects.hashCode(nome_posto_saude, endereco, cidade);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof PostoSaude) {
        PostoSaude other = (PostoSaude) obj;
        // Google Guava provides great utilities for equals too!
        return Objects.equal(nome_posto_saude, other.nome_posto_saude)
                && Objects.equal(endereco, other.endereco)
                && cidade == other.cidade;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-        app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value> org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext         </param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>palmaslab.mapas.config</param-value>
 </init-param>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

 </servlet-mapping>
<context-param>  
<param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>  
<param-value>dev</param-value>  
</context-param>  
<context-param>  
<param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>  
<param-value>dev</param-value>  
</context-param>
<context-param>  
<param-name>spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain</param-name>  
<param-value>dev</param-value>  
</context-param>  
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.

Comment: Ok sorry. Any one could help me please? Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling during a few days i found a solution. When i do @EnableAutoConfiguration in my application.java,it seems that the mapped URIs in the DispatcherServlet are deleted or unconfigured. So,  [here](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/011-add-servlet-mapping-to-dispatcherservlet-spring-boot/#modifying-dispatch-servlet-path) explains how to add a new URI on the main DispatcherServlet. In the first method it takes the DispatchServlet and in the second one it add a new URI.